# Start EditText input on a TextView click

Tags: android

Is there a way to start EditText input (display keyboard to enter text in EditText field) when you click on a TextView?

```
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by editor/

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to show an `EditText` widget whenever you press the `TextView`?

Comment: clarify your question please

Comment: Why using a textView if you want editText?

Comment: edittext.requestfocus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               myEditTextView.requestFocus();
               InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.showSoftInput(myEditTextView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet might help:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText edittext = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
EditText textView = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          edittext.requestFocus();
          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          etInput.requestFocus();
          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.showSoftInput(etInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

You need to add **InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Answer (score 0):

**onClick Of Textview**:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openKeyboard();
    }
});
```

**Method to open keyboard**:

```
private void openKeyboard() {
    etInput.requestFocus();
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(etInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```